# [GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1028e2450

Tags: swift, google-maps, frameworks, cocoapods, static-libraries

In my project, I have added a pod of Google map so I have Project A with Google Map and framework also have Google. So both Project A and Framework B have Google Map When I have added the Framework I am facing a crash while opening the Map View

While doing the debugging if I removed the google map from framework B and adding the framework in Project it's not crashing

So as per my understanding, the reason for the crash is adding the Google Map Pod in both Project A and Framework B

Is any one having idea to resolve this issue?

```
[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1028e2450
2019-06-25 12:58:15.905674+0530 Boost[535:26666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1028e2450'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1f68d5ea4 0x1f5aa5a50 0x1f67f3bbc 0x1f68db7bc 0x1f68dd46c 0x101393d48 0x1013fedc8 0x1013fe3b4 0x101409264 0x101405fe0 0x101401614 0x10123aaa8 0x10123a3fc 0x106c27824 0x106c28dc8 0x106c2c1c4 0x106c2b604 0x106c3a1dc 0x106c3abc8 0x1f64f117c 0x1f64f3cec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I have a shared pod in both project target and framework and added apikey in both but still I get this error. Any Update?

Comment: any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: Was anything found? I have the same question

Comment: found anything on this?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only fix this by making sure there is only one framework that rely on GoogleMap pod.